# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory

Здравствуйте в консоли гугла часто встречается данная ошибка во вкладке сбои и anr. Я так понимаю нехватка памяти для приложения. Но как с этим бороться?

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
>   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
>   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:611)
>   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:354)
>   at com.EdwardSark.cutoutascene.Room14.onCreate(Room14.java:230)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: [Надо правильно работать с bitmap -ами](http://bit.ly/14pVoZA)

Comment: Но я не использовал в приложении bitmap.

Comment: Уверены? Bitmap это просто обычные картинки

Comment: Я думал это способ их представления(картинок). Еще такой вопрос при запуске приложения, он будто все его ресурсы грузит в VM(главным образом картинки), в результате чего он жрет около 45 мб оперативки. Можно ли как-то подгружать нужные в данный момент ресурсы, а не используемые нет? Надеюсь я понятно все написал?))

Comment: ImageView imgView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.img);
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.at1);
    delate(imgView)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!