# Возможно ли и как победить java.lang.OutOfMemoryError в моем случае?

Tags: android, изображения, outofmemoryerror

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
имя пакета.MainActivity.onCreate
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:background="@drawable/button_task">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/line1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/good_text_0"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/good_text_1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/good_text_2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/good_text_3"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/good_text_4"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/good_text_5"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame2"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


</FrameLayout>
```

Код:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
DB db;
TextView text_0, text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4, text_5;
ImageView image1, image2;
LinearLayout line1;
FrameLayout frame2;
Animation anim, anim_im_1, anim_im_0;
int stringID, j;
String package_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // полноэкранный "липкий" режим
    lipkiy();

    // воспроизведение песни
    // создаем плеер и указываем ему нужный файл для проигрывания
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.serdtse);
    // создаем менеджер управления громкостью звука
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // устанавливаем громкость звука
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, (maxVolume * 9) / 10, 0);
    // воспроизвести только 1 раз
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.start();

    //При завершении воспроизводства очистить приогрыватель
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });

    //получаем данные из файла "Pref"
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ed = sPref.edit();
    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();
    nachalo();
}
// приветствие и начало работы
protected void nachalo()
{
    text_0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_0);
    text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    text_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    text_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
    text_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_4);
    text_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_5);

    package_name = getApplicationContext() . getPackageName();
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);


    line1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line1);
    frame2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame2);


    // создаем объект анимации из файла anim/myalpha
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myalpha);
    anim_im_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_image_1);
    anim_im_0 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_image_0);



    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

                for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    ed . putInt("i", i);
                    ed . commit();
                    runOnUiThread(runn0); //появление  с анимацией
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(4000); // пауза для показа надписи
                    runOnUiThread(runn0_1); //исчезновение
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1950); // пауза для анимации
                    runOnUiThread(runn0_2); //невидимая надпись
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // пауза пустой экран
                }

               runOnUiThread(run_frame); // видимый новый фрейм



                for ( int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
                {
                    ed . putInt("i", i);
                    ed . commit();
                    runOnUiThread(run_image);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1950);
                    //runOnUiThread(run_image_2);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(8800);
                }
                runOnUiThread(runn6);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

Runnable run_frame = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // делаем видимым слайды
        frame2 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        line1 . setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
};

Runnable run_image = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // запускаем анимацию
        switch (sPref.getInt("i", 0)) // в зависимости от номера
        {
            case 0: //первый слайд
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_0);
                image1 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);

                break;

            case 1: // второй слайд
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_1);
                image2 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 2: // слайд 3
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_2);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 3: // слайд 4
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_3);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 4: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_4);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 5: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_5);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 6: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_6);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 7: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_7);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 8: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_8);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 9: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_9);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 10: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_10);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 11: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_11);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 12: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_12);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 13: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_13);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 14: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_14);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 15: // версия два
                image2 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_15);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 16: // версия два
                image1 . setImageResource(R.drawable.k_16);
                image1 . startAnimation(anim_im_1);
                image2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;
        }


    }
};


Runnable runn0 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // запускаем анимацию
        switch (sPref.getInt("i", 0)) // в зависимости от номера
        {
            case 0: //первый запуск
                text_0 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_0 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 1: // версия один
                text_1 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_1 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 2: // версия два
                text_2 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_2 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 3: // версия два
                text_3 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_3 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 4: // версия два
                text_4 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_4 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 5: // версия два
                text_5 . startAnimation(anim);
                text_5 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
    }
};

Runnable runn0_1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // запускаем анимацию
        switch (sPref.getInt("i", 0)) // в зависимости от номера
        {
            case 0: //первый запуск
                text_0 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 1: // версия один
                text_1 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 2: // версия два
                text_2 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 3: // версия два
                text_3 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 4: // версия два
                text_4 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;

            case 5: // версия два
                text_5 . startAnimation(anim_im_0);
                break;
        }
    }
};

Runnable runn0_2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // запускаем анимацию
        switch (sPref.getInt("i", 0)) // в зависимости от номера
        {
            case 0: //первый запуск
                text_0 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 1: // версия один
                text_1 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 2: // версия два
                text_2 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 3: // версия два
                text_3 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 4: // версия два
                text_4 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 5: // версия два
                text_5 . setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
};


Runnable runn6 = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FAQ.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.alpha_to_1, R.anim.alpha_to_0);
    }
};
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    db.close();
}
// полноэкранный "липкий" режим
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    lipkiy();
}

// полноэкранный "липкий" режим
protected void lipkiy ()
{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
}
```

Буду признателен за конкретные предложения с примерами кода.

Comment: Подскажите, а зачем так много imageView в вашей разметке ? Я боюсь, что проблема в том, что у Вас слишком много изображений. Пересмотрите логику, может можно использовать RecyclerView или сделать изображения минимального размера.

Comment: Вам не нужны 17 `ImageView`, поскольку одновременно могут быть видны только два. Смысл такой: когда слайд отработал и уже скрыт меняем в нём картинку, отменяем то что сделала анимация и переиспользуем для следующего слайда.

Comment: @woesss, первоначально я тоже по вашей логике создал только 2 imageView и попеременно загружал туда изображения. Однако столкнулся с непредвиденной сложностью: я не смог добиться динамической загрузки изображения через stringID = getResources().getIdentifier("k_" + j, "drawable", package_name); а затем присвоения его ImageView внутри Runnable run_image = new Runnable(). Размер каждого изображения 28 - 46 КБ. RecyclerView - все же с 5.0, а ошибка возникает как раз у пользователей с андроид 4.2 - 4.4.

Comment: К чему эти извращения? `id` ресурсов заранее известны и в том же `swith` Вы знаете какой ресурс нужен. А если хотите обращаться к ним по порядковому номеру, можно положить их в интовый массив и брать по индексу:     
`private int[] ids = { R.drawable.k_0, R.drawable.k_1, ...};`     
...    
`imageView.setImageResource(ids[j]);`

Comment: @woesss, я Вас ввел в заблуждение, объясняя почему создал 17 ImageView. Только сейчас, когда вернулся к двум и получил тот же эффект, вспомнил причину: при двух ImageView воспроизведение файла mp3 прерывается. Я это связал с тем, что ImageView присваевается рисунок из ресурсов и эта процедура останавливает воспроизведение. Подскажите что-то в этой связи? P.S. а первоначальные извращения были связаны с желанием названия ресурсов перебирать в цикле, а не руками. Теперь, когда все 17 случаев расписаны, Вы абсолютно правы, можно и прописать руками. Новый код исправлю в вопросе.

Comment: Это уже другая тема - поэтому задайте новый вопрос, а этот верните в исходную, чтобы не сбивать с толку других посетителей

Comment: @woesss, тогда целесообразнее его удалить, ибо он не имеет проверенных ответов, содержит больше дискуссий, и представляется скорее искусственным.

Comment: @St-st, да и отвечали по этой теме уже не раз. Так что я - за!

Answer (score 1):

Есть три варианта решения вашей проблемы. Для большей эффективности лучше использовать все три :

Первый. Как предложил @Vitaly Tomashevsky в комменте выше - перекроить разметку и добавить в нее `RecyclerView`, вместо кучи `ImageView`

Второй. Оптимизировать сами изображения, сжав их через любой подобный сервис. Например [такой](http://optimizilla.com/ru/).

Третий, наиболее действенный. Воспользоваться библиотекой Picasso.
Для этого в Gradle пишем:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

}
```

В коде, где надо:

`Picasso.with(активность).load(R.drawable.ваш_img).into(R.id.ваш_ImageView);`

и добавляем картинки динамически.

Обычно все три составляющие снимают мои проблемы с OOM :)

Comment: я бы заменил Picasso на Glide - при всех прочих равных, Glide потребляет меньше ресурсов и шустрее работает, но весит побольше чем Picasso.

Comment: Сжатие файлов через подобные сервисы здесь не поможет. Это только может уменьшить размер apk, но никак не справится с OOM. Так как `ImageView` хранит в памяти `Bitmap`, то тут на размер занимаемой памяти влияет исключительно размер изображения (ширина и высота) и режим битмапа. А как оно представлено в виде файла всё равно. Хоть там png хоть jpeg, хоть с потерями хоть без потерь.

Comment: Размер каждого изображения в рамках 28 - 46 КБ. RecyclerView - все же с 5.0, а ошибка возникает как раз у пользователей с андроид 4.2 - 4.4. Я склонялся к тому, что неправильно работаю с изображениями. dokupash советует использовать ImageView imgView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.img); imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.at1); delate(imgView) в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241281/java-lang-outofmemoryerror, но я не понимаю как работает и работает ли его предложение.

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky.  Можете ли Вы объяснить, что делает Picasso и Glide? Нужно ли дополнительно загружать библиотеку Picasso и Glide, или достаточно добавить 2 строчки, которые указаны в ответе?

Comment: @St-st в ответе в первой строчке - подключение библиотеки в Gradle, вторая строка это использование библиотеки для загрузки изображения. Picasso и Glide просто оптимизируют работу с изображениями, причем они очень похожи в использовании - но есть кардинальные различия в механизмах, лично я считаю что Glide это подпиленная Picasso. Если у вас в проекте используется много изображений - вам однозначно неоюходимо использовать сторонние библиотеки а не городить свои обработки, и время сэкономите и оптимизация будет в разы выше.

Comment: переход на `RecyclerView` в вашем случае на память вряд ли сильно повлияет :) Но сделает код красивее и логичней. Или GridLaoyut. Для API 7+ есть `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1` и `com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1` (это туда же, в `dependencies`)

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky, столкнулся с ошибками синтаксиса (уже после dependencies): Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.k_0).into(R.id.image0); 1. Если просто написать название активности в скобках, Андроид-Стидия подчеркиевает красным, решает вопрос добавления this. 2. Но тогда идет подчеркиевание (R.id.image0) - пишет, что не может разобрать метод инту.Второй вопрос: что значит "добавляем картинки динамически"? Если я рядом с отождествлением переменных с ImageView (image0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image0); и т.д.) вставлю сразу 17 Picasso.with(активность)...- это будет динамически?

Comment: Динамически - в коде, не через разметку, для каждого отдельно. Вместо `R.id.image0` можно писать вашу переменную `image0`. Либо сразу `(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image0)`

Comment: К сожалению не строит апк-файл: Error:Execution failed for task ':пакет:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. Серия предупреждений: "Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient". УТОЧНЯЮ: я добавил зависимость в файл Gradle для модуля, т.е. там, где указывается номер версии, minSdkVersion и т.д. Стоит настройка "proguard-android-optimize.txt" ProGuard, version 5.2.1 В чем может быть подвох?

Comment: да, не стал указывать, думал неважно.. у Пикассо в Прогвардом проблема :-/ сам пока не нашел как решить, хотя пытал. Попробуйте Glide? Если у вас получится совместить Пикассо и Прогвард буду благодарен за опыт ;)

Comment: Как поставить Glide? :) Если возможно, пошагово и с кодом :)

Comment: посмотрите, в описании на Гите все инструкции https://github.com/bumptech/glide :)

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich, картинки лежат в ресурсах - следовательно они уже оптимизированы по размерам и плотностям. В чём будет профит от Glide или Picasso?

Comment: @woesss Picasso (и, вероятно, Glide) кэширует картинки. А постоянное обращение к ресурсам требует больше памяти.

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich,  кеширование в памяти требует меньше памяти? Или чтение из дискового кэша сильно отличается от чтения из ресурсов? Что-то не видится мне в этом плане выгоды...

Comment: @woesss предложите ваш метод борьбы с ООМ при работе с `ImageView`