# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, помогите решить проблему

Tags: java, android

Когда я выложил свою игру в google play, в отчете об тестировании прислали ошибку java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Читал в интернете, ничего так и не понял. Пытался поэкспериментировать, но безрезультатно.
Вот что мне прислали:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-957
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:130)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:46)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:456)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.ilyacynep.thelife.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:124)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:14)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:31)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:132)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:126)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:42)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:75)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:16)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:11)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:33)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
```

как решить проблему и чем она связана?
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Ищите утечки памяти в приложении. Используйте LeakCanary

Comment: com.ilyacynep.thelife.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:124), что на этой строке?

Comment: int showhidebotsandmachinesvalue переменная

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241281/java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Возможно у вас просто слишком большая картинка. Если так - сделайте оную в разных размерах для разных параметров экрана.

Comment: А почему тогда если изображение большое главное меню открывается? А потом если нажать "играть" ошибка выскакивает

Comment: в главном меню тоже большая картинка

Comment: В студии есть профилирование при запуске приложения, нужно смотреть сколько оно потребляет памяти и после каких действий - иначе можно только гадать. Т.к. ошибка только указывает в каком месте не хватило памяти, а что конкретно съело память не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего устанавливать картинку через Glide или Picasso. Они генерируют в кэше маленькое превью по размеру ImageView. Тогда утечек памяти быть не должно.